# Parent Took Precedence Over Child on DIV Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a `div` and within the `div` there is a child `img` element.
Both `div` and `img` have their very own javascript `click handler`.

My objective is to have when I click on the `img`, only the `img click` is triggered.
But currently the `div click handler` is responding before the `img click handler`.

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/5j73w/

I'm not sure if parent's `position: relative` is the culprit. But that's a compulsory style.
I also tried with `z-index` for `img` but no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the deprecated [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) by [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as you're using jQuery 1.7+.

```
$('#parent > img').on('click', function(e) {
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5j73w/3/)**

Or, if you need the event delegation (e.g. in case you're adding content dynamically to `#parent`):

```
//run this line when #parent is in the DOM
$('#parent').on('click', '> img', function(e) {
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5j73w/5/)

`.live` bubbles the event all the way up to the document to then check if the given selector matches the target element, by then you can't stop the event propagation anymore. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Calling `event.stopPropagation()` in the event handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has already propagated to `document`.

Also, to answer the "parent takes precedence" question, that's not case. When you call `.live`, you're actually attaching a handler to the `document`.

In this case, the handler attached through `.click(function(){})` (which in jQuery 1.7+ is a shorthand for `.on('click'[, null], function(){})`, executes before the handler attached to the `document`, which is the expected event propagation bubbling behavior.

Comment: Found out that I was using v1.6.2 on my backend system. Upgraded to v1.8.0 and changed the `live` to `on` turns out working perfectly! Thanks for the solution and detail explanation too.

Comment: No problem. Just added some more detail on the "culprit" part, also for jQuery 1.6.2 you could use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), but as you've upgraded then `.on` is the best option. `=]`

Answer (score 2):

Was able to fix by doing the following:

```
$('#parent').click(function(e)
{
    console.log("parent click");
});


$('#child').click(function(e)
{
    console.log("child click");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

​

Here's the [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JVsAw/)